# Difference between every and filter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was wondering which of the functions among `Array.prototype.every` and `Array.prototype.filter` are fast in javascript?
The difference that I know is that every can be stopped by returning false and filter cannot stop by returning false.
Apart from this difference is there any other?
And if which one among this has indexing?

Comment: Filter is faster. Check out: http://jsperf.com/filter-and-every-vs-filter-vs-remove

Comment: @NabRaj that jsperf is not actually testing the array prototype methods in question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The functions do completely different things.

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will create an array of all the elements matching your condition in the callback

```
function isBigEnough(element) {
  return element >= 10;
}
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
// filtered is [12, 130, 44]
```

[`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) will return true if every element in the array matches your condition in the callback

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
  return (element >= 10);
}
var passed = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);
// passed is false
passed = [12, 54, 18, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);
// passed is true
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.filter` returns an array of the matched data from the given array.

`Array.prototype.every` will always return boolean value according to the given conditions.

Answer (score -1):

[`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

Determines whether all the members of an array like `a[*] == b[*]` satisfy the specified test.
(**complete truth**).

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

just like testing `x exists IN [*]`
(**truth if at least one matches**)

Comment: okay. what I felt was one method tests for every thing and the other returns immediately when a match found. I believe we can not judge on their speed which breaks their meaning.